# Split an array of char without using strtok in C

Tags: c

I would like to split an array in char whenever it gets an empty space.

For example, if the given char chars[] = "Test Me".

The return value should be:

**Test**

**Me**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "strtok.h"

static char *next = NULL;

char *custom_strtok(char *str)
{
        next = custom_strtok(" ,.-");
        while(next != NULL) {
            printf ("%s\n",next);
            next = custom_strtok(" ,.-");
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

How can I split the char array with a space without using strtok?

Comment: strchr is your friend

Comment: I don't see much code in this function. Can you make a bit more of an effort than this? See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would look through the list of functions provided by the C `<string.h>` header file in the C Standard Library and you'd find a lot of options.

I wrote something just for fun:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct token {
  const char *str;
  size_t len;
};

struct token next_token(const char *str, const char *sep) {
  struct token tok;
  /* skip leading separator characters */
  str += strspn(str, sep);
  tok.str = str;
  tok.len = strcspn(str, sep);
  return tok;
}

struct token *get_tokens(const char *str, const char *sep) {
  size_t len = 0, cap = 8;
  struct token *arr = malloc(cap * sizeof *arr);

  for (struct token tok = next_token(str, sep); tok.len;
       tok = next_token(tok.str + tok.len, sep)) {
    arr[len] = tok;
    ++len;
    if (len == cap) {
      cap *= 2;
      arr = realloc(arr, cap * sizeof *arr);
    }
  }
  arr[len].str = NULL;
  arr[len].len = 0;
  return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  puts("Token array");
  struct token *token_arr = get_tokens(argv[1], " \t\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; token_arr[i].str; ++i) {
    printf("\"%.*s\" ", (int)token_arr[i].len, token_arr[i].str);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  free(token_arr);

  puts("Next token loop");
  for (struct token tok = next_token(argv[1], " \t\n"); tok.len;
       tok = next_token(tok.str + tok.len, " \t\n")) {
    printf("\"%.*s\" ", (int)tok.len, tok.str);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```