# Split string without using strtok() in C

Tags: c

I am trying to split a sentence into an array of the individual words.

I have recently realized that I cannot use strtok() in this function and am now looking for an alternative way to implement this function without using strtok(). Does anyone know how I can go about this?

Edit:

I need to return a pointer to an array of pointer pointing to the individual words in the sentence.

Comment: Why can't you use `strtok()`? Are there other functions you're not allowed to use?

Comment: Consider `strcspn()`

Comment: Consider finding the seperater by using `strchr()` and writing terminators 'by hand'.

Comment: Yeah, you write your own version of `strtok`. It would iterate each character of the string until it find one of the delim characters and replaces it with `\0`. Have you attempted that?

Comment: @Barmar obviously, `strtok()` modifies the input string, and that memory may be read-only

Comment: @VladFeinstein So make a copy of it first. The replacement will have to make copies of the tokens as it finds them.

Comment: @kaylum What would replacing the character with \0 do?

Comment: @Dash That's what strotk does. The effect is to break the string into two strings - before and after the delimiter. But as others have pointed out, if you just want to handle a fixed delimiter of `" "` you don't necessarily need to write a full `strtok` replacement. Can use more targeted solution such as `strchr`. But it depends whether you want a general `strtok` replacement or solve just this specific problem.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to change `theString`, it should be declared as `const char *theString` to make that clear. You also need to explain what the outputs of the function are supposed to be.

Comment: @user3386109 I just made an edit with the output of the function.

Comment: @Dash - if you want the `res` - you'd have to make a copy of your read-only string (and free it at some point). Alternatively, look at my answer below - you would have pointers to the beginning of each string, but when you use it - you'd have to look for the following space character.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strchr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm) instead of `strtok()`

**UPDATE**

The OP needs to clarify what exactly he wants to get from this `splitString` function?

It returns an array of pointers to separated words. That's fine if he used `strtok`, as it would terminate each word with `0`.

If those `0`'s are not inserted, the resulting array, while still pointing to the beginning of each word, would have no indication of their lengths. That should be handled by the user of this array.

Comment: Not sure that's a good way. `strtok` can handle multiple delimiters in one call. So using `strchr` would require potentially iterating the string multiple times.

Comment: Ah, good point. My bad. Too focused on a replacing `strtok` and missed the possible simplification.

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit to the post. I need to return a pointer to an array of pointers to each individual string. I cannot use strtok() as it modifies the input string and that memory is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my answer to a now closed question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63866151/13422

You would look through the list of functions provided by the C `<string.h>` header file in the C Standard Library and you'd find a lot of options.

I wrote something just for fun:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct token {
  const char *str;
  size_t len;
};

struct token next_token(const char *str, const char *sep) {
  struct token tok;
  /* skip leading separator characters */
  str += strspn(str, sep);
  tok.str = str;
  tok.len = strcspn(str, sep);
  return tok;
}

struct token *get_tokens(const char *str, const char *sep) {
  size_t len = 0, cap = 8;
  struct token *arr = malloc(cap * sizeof *arr);

  for (struct token tok = next_token(str, sep); tok.len;
       tok = next_token(tok.str + tok.len, sep)) {
    arr[len] = tok;
    ++len;
    if (len == cap) {
      cap *= 2;
      arr = realloc(arr, cap * sizeof *arr);
    }
  }
  arr[len].str = NULL;
  arr[len].len = 0;
  return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  puts("Token array");
  struct token *token_arr = get_tokens(argv[1], " \t\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; token_arr[i].str; ++i) {
    printf("\"%.*s\" ", (int)token_arr[i].len, token_arr[i].str);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  free(token_arr);

  puts("Next token loop");
  for (struct token tok = next_token(argv[1], " \t\n"); tok.len;
       tok = next_token(tok.str + tok.len, " \t\n")) {
    printf("\"%.*s\" ", (int)tok.len, tok.str);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How could I modify the function I have above to do this same thing? I need to return a pointer to an array of pointers to strings. With the strings being the individual words in the sentence.

Comment: @Dash well what are your options? You can copy each word out of the original string, if you cannot modify it. Or you can set the character at tok.len to 0 then it would be strtok. Or my favorite in real code, just use the pointer and the length. You cannot really trust zero-terminated strings anyway.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use the pointer and the length to determine this now although I cannot figure out how the code should look.

Comment: @Dash You are stuck if you absolutely have to return a `char**` then you can't use pointer + length.

Comment: @Dash anyway, I wasn't going to write the code for you just share a similar solution to give you an idea of a way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it helped me understand it a little better. I think I am just stuck at the part where I need to allocate a new pointer to the word out of the original string as I'm not sure how to do that while allocating the new memory to it as well.

Comment: @Dash you have an array of pointers you are growing with realloc. You can create a new memory allocation with malloc (+1 for the terminating zero character) and strcpy or memcpy into the new allocation, then assign that pointer into your array of pointers.

Comment: @Dash or alternatively you could copy the entire string from theString then you are free to mangle it however you like using strtok or your own function. Then you can set string terminating zeros at the end of every word and return an array of character pointers.

Comment: @Dash Copying the entire string is a good idea. And a preprocessing pass that counts the number of words would allow you to allocate memory for the pointer array. Then you don't need `realloc` at all.